# How can i view the disk latency of a ZFS pool, or of the disks in it?

Tags: freebsd, performance, iowait

I'm using FreeBSD. I would like to write a munin plugin to log it, but i don't understand how to get this data.

Comment: I have a feeling that the answer will involve `dtrace`, however I'm not familiar enough with the technology to write a full answer on this subject...

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there's a way to measure this directly without abusing dtrace.

Some things that may be helpful:

- [`gstat(8)`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gstat&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%209.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) - Geom device statistics, can show you raw disk activity / workload
  Doesn't directly measure latency though.
- [ioping](http://code.google.com/p/ioping/) - Lets you measure latency from userland (you could run it & log/chart the results)
  Downside: Adds load to do the test, passes through the VFS layer, and can't test the underlying drive unless you reserve a partition for it to use.